# Mod_Rewrite: Rewrite Rules confilicting with each other

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the home page which is mydomain.com to mydomain.com/index.php?cat=home

here is my htacess file rules:

```
RewriteRule index.php  index.php?cat=home [L]
RewriteRule (.*)-live-streaming-online.html  index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

when both are active every page in my site whatever the cat is redirected to index.php?cat=home

what is wrong with this htacess?

Comment: @JonLin can u help with this?

Comment: add $ at the end of the first rewrite rule also '.' has a special meaning, use '\.' instead

Comment: @Mahakala  clarify your answer please, i tried / but non working

Comment: try this: RewriteRule index\.php$  index.php?cat=home [L]

Comment: @Mahakala tried this but it make 2nd rule non working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-live-streaming-online\.html$ /index.php?cat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(index\.php)?[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?cat=home [L]
```

Key is to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` which represents original request received by Apache. Other using URI patten from `RewriteRule` can change based on your other rule.

Comment: it give 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: it worked but not what i want i want the url still appear as mydomain.com while it load mydomain.com/index.php?cat=home

Comment: Yes my rule doesn't change the URL in your browser since I am not using any `R` flag here. You may have some other rules doing that.

Comment: If you have other rules then post your complete .htaccess in your question.